# Data modelling for consistent secondary keys with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql, cassandra-2.0

With Cassandra,

I want to represent all users objects with a unique `uuid`, but also contain a set of zero or more secondary user keys to map to a user. Each secondary key should map to one and only one user(id). Because I need to be able to quick lookup of secondarykey to find a user, I maintain a separate lookup table, instead of a secondary `INDEX`.

I've modelled the data like this, but I am open to alternatives:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    userid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    secondarykeys set<text>
);
CREATE TABLE user_secondarykeys (
    secondarykey text,
    userid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY(secondarykey)
);
```

A typical use case is this:

I got this user with a secondary key `mail:andreas@example.org`, and I would like to see if there exists any user with that secondary key, and if it do not exists, I would like to create a new user object.

I can look for the secondary key:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "user_secondarykeys" WHERE secondarykey = "mail:andreas@example.org";
```

and if I do not find any matches, I can insert a new user:

```sql
BEGIN BATCH
    INSERT INTO users (userid, name, secondarykeys) VALUES (77059e45-5fac-460b-9c4f-47528c292be0, "Andreas", {'mail:andreas@example.org'});
    INSERT INTO user_secondarykeys (secondarykey, userid) VALUES ('mail:andreas@example.org', 77059e45-5fac-460b-9c4f-47528c292be0);
APPLY BATCH;
```

My problem is that this can lead to inconsistent data, because a user can be inserted with that secondary key in the meantime between my select and my inserts.

I'm thinking that if I can make my INSERT transaction fail if the secondary key already exists in user_secondarykeys, that would work, because it should then also revert the insert into the users table, because of the atomic property of the transaction. However, I do not know any ways to make the INSERT fail if the secondary key exists. If I add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the second insert, it will not revert the trasaction it will just avoid inserting into `user_secondarykeys`, but it will still insert into `users`.

Any suggestions on how to implement this use case in a reliable way is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think that your model is pretty complicated, and I'm not sure if I understand correctly all of your requirements.

So if you get at first this secondary key, and then you have to decide what to do - add user or not - then the following will work for you:

Instead of checking user_secondarykeys table with SELECT statement for occurrence of particular secondary key, go with the following:

```
INSERT INTO user_secondarykeys (secondarykey, userid) VALUES ('mail:andreas@example.org', 77059e45-5fac-460b-9c4f-47528c292be0) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

So if it applies, it means that this secondary key is not connected with any user - so there are two cases: user doesn't exists or user exists and someone want's to add new secondary key for him. The following will do the job in both cases:

```
INSERT INTO users(userid, name, secondarykeys) VALUES(77059e45-5fac-460b-9c4f-47528c292be0, 'Andreas', secondarykeys = secondarykeys + 'mail:andreas@example.org')
```

Because inserts/updates in Cassandra are idempotent(except counters), this will work even if there will be already an user with that id in users table - this should just add another secondary key for him.

Pros of this solution are that you will remove this gap in time which can make you 'inconsistent'. You have a guarantee that no one will insert two users with the same secondary key. You specified that user can have no secondary keys at all - in this situation you can add him straight to the users table.

> I'm thinking that if I can make my INSERT transaction fail if the secondary key already exists in user_secondarykeys, that would work, because it should then also revert the insert into the users table, because of the atomic property of the transaction. However, I do not know any ways to make the INSERT fail if the secondary key exists. If I add IF NOT EXISTS to the second insert, it will not revert the trasaction it will just avoid inserting into user_secondarykeys, but it will still insert into users.

Since Cassandra 2.0.6 you can use a conditional statements inside a batch, and if any of conditions will be not met then all instructions in that batch won't fire. This sounds great but there is a limitation - all of the statements inside batch have to operate on the single, same partition. According to this, it is impossible to make cross partition/table conditional insert/update/delete. So in your case this:

```
BEGIN BATCH
    INSERT INTO users (userid, name, secondarykeys) VALUES (77059e45-5fac-460b-9c4f-47528c292be0, "Andreas", {'mail:andreas@example.org'});
    INSERT INTO user_secondarykeys (secondarykey, userid) VALUES ('mail:andreas@example.org', 77059e45-5fac-460b-9c4f-47528c292be0) IF NOT EXISTS;
APPLY BATCH;
```

would not even pass the query validation, because you try here to operate on two different tables.

I'm not sure if this will be suitable for other of your requirements, I would need more information about your queries and the velocity/volume of the data. For sure there are other ways for modeling this.

It would greatly simplify the problem if every user would have to have at least one specified secondary key(e.g. email would be a great unique key for your users table), but that's are your requirements, so unless you can't change them there is no discussion.

Hope this will help you a bit. 
Good luck!